# How to open other screen with fade in in react-native?

Tags: react-native

*I have 5 screen in Scene. What I want is that when I move between screens, I want to open nextpage with fade in. is it possible ?*

**these are my screens :**

```
  <Scene key="Main" duration={0}  hideNavBar >
              <Scene key="user" component={UserScreen}  initial/>
              <Scene key="selectRota" component={ChooseRota} />
              <Scene key="passengerScreenOne" component={passengerScreenOne}/>
              <Scene key="passengerScreenTwo"  component={passengerScreenTwo}  />
              <Scene key="passengerScreenThree" component={passengerScreenThree} />
  </Scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

use react native navigation and [react native navigation transition](https://github.com/plmok61/react-navigation-transitions)

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { fadeIn } from 'react-navigation-transitions';
import ScreenA from './ScreenA';
import ScreenB from './ScreenB';

const appStack = createStackNavigator(
{
ScreenA: {
  screen: ScreenA,
},
ScreenB: {
  screen: ScreenB,
},
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'ScreenA',
  transitionConfig: () => fadeIn(),
},
);
```

Comment: I know that way, I just want to learn how to do this with Router ?